# Symfony 2. Migration project to php 7 from php5.5. Performance issues

Tags: php, performance, symfony, php-7

I have one project ~4y old, I started with 5.3 and Symfony 2.0, migrated to 5.5 and S2.3. At the moment I migrated to S2.8 and I want to migrate to php 7.

As there was so much heap around PHP 7 performance I was eager to test my project performance in dev env.

So running benchmark in dev env; service is on vagrant host having both php5-fpm and php7.0-fpm, shutting one down and setting another up.

I would expect that php7 would outperform php5, but basically it seems that php7 **is 1.5-2 times slower** on my local dev env.

What am I doing wrong? Or should I rewrite my app somehow?

phpinfo: 
php 7 http://pastebin.com/a6a76vE2
php 5 http://pastebin.com/4GBXNmBB

P.S. Yes, I understand that running benchmarks in local dev env is not 100% valid and pure, but I need only to understand if php7 faster than php5, as it said.

**U1**

Funniest thing is that blackfire shows clearly that php 7 is ~45% faster than php 5. But when I am sieging, than I see that performance degrades.

**U2**

Here is more or less my custom configuration for dev env. It is the same for php5.5 and php7:

```
[Date]
date.timezone = Europe/Tallinn

[PHP]
memory_limit = 512M
expose_php = Off
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0
post_max_size = 10M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
max_execution_time = 60
realpath_cache_size = 4096k
realpath_cache_ttl = 7200

error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php.errors.log

display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
html_errors = On

; xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"

[opcache]
opcache.enable_cli=0
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=66000
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=5
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
```

Comment: @VaheShadunts, well great for you. Any hints what to look at? Might be some opcache settings, app config tweaks or bootstrap caching?

Comment: Did you try to run your tests on another machine or with a different configuration?

Comment: @A.L I think my problem is more related to configuration, than to machine. But not sure what to look for. Basically php-fpm config is the same, pool config is the same. Code is the same. So I have no clear clue.

Comment: Did you enable `opcache` in PHP7?

Comment: Jevgeni, do you make "composer update" after php version switch? because bundles may have different versions for php5 and php7 versions.

Comment: @DenisAlimov, cleared cache and reinstalled everything. seems not the case.

Comment: 1. Are you sure all PHP modules that you run under 5.5 you also run under 7.0?  2. I would test anything without xdebug enabled (for both versions)

Comment: You should disable xdebug before doing any  performance testing.

Comment: if you are using apc cache, PHP7 renamed this library and Symfony Classes changed too. You must use apcu for all apc definitions.

Comment: Vagrant uses a hypervisor's sharing folders ability. From my experience, switching to anything else will boost up your application significantly.

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov Have you checked for notices and warnings in the logs? When I updated my project from PHP 5.X to 7.X I had a lot of notices and warnings that were getting through unnoticed before. They could be related to your performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Few steps to optimize PHP code globally and for PHP7 :

- composer selfupdate
- composer update
- composer dumpautoload -a
- activate zend opcache (or any other installed php opcache)
- in php.ini :

  - opcache.max_accelerated_files=20000 (or more)
  - opcache.validate_timestamps=1
  - opcache.revalidate_freq=10 (or more)
  - xdebug.default_enable=0
- restart php-fpm7 service

If performance issues still persist, profile your typical test page with [blackfire](https://blackfire.io).

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this will surely be the xdebug. Please turn it off and then check the performance.

I have to point out that in our case after switching from PHP5.5/Symfony 2.0 to PHP7/Symfony 3.0 we did encountered a performance drop. This was caused by how Symfony 2.8+ handles the php sessions. It stores them in a local directory instead of standard /tmp directory which almost always stored in RAM. So if you have pretty big count of session files the search of the file from HDD takes a long time compared to RAM.

After removing this in Symfony config, the application started showing the performance gains we hoped for.